# How-to manual add unique for all table in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I use sails-mongo for working with models, I have a few attr with unique: true, but recently, this option does not work in the [bug tracker](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/181) said that it is necessary to add yourself this unique option, and then run using the migrate: safe. But I do not know how to mongo independently assign this option to automatically add and check. Tell me what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to your mongodb (e.g. with mongo-console).

Use this:

```
db.YOURCOLLECTION.ensureIndex( { YOURFIELD: 1 }, { unique: true } );
```